# Montar relatorio em Java

Tags: java, swing

Estou fazendo um sistema com swing como trabalho da faculdade e no final de cada ciclo de dias do programa queria que ele gerasse um relatório. Alguém sabe como funciona para montar relatório em Java?

Comment: Montar um relatório, no meu ponto de vista, é apresentar as informações de forma ordenada e clara ao usuário.  Como você está utilizando Swing, pode se exibir o relatório em  tela.

Comment: esse relatório seria gerado automaticamente no final de cada dia ou você que iria gera-los?

Comment: A principio seria gerado quando solicitado. Como nunca montei relatório em nem uma outra linguagem também. Queria saber como funciona a dinâmica de montar. Se tem algum segredo. as vezes chamar algum outro programa para jogar as informações.

Comment: Veja se ajuda: http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/artigos/tutorial-criando-relatorios-com-jasperreports-primeiros-passos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu particularmente utilizo o JasperReports para confeccionar os meus relatórios em Java.
Ele é muito semelhante ao Crystal Reports para o Visual Studio C#, porém o JasperSoft Studio funciona de forma independente, você pode gerar e importar os seus arquivos de relatórios para seu sistema e utilizar a biblioteca fornecida para fazer os relatórios funcionarem.

Vale muito a pena dar uma olhada. Segue o link: http://community.jaspersoft.com/

Comment: Cara, que bacana! vou tentar adaptar no meu código. Obrigado.

Comment: Faça isso, eu aqui uso bastante quando tenho que fazer relatórios em Java.
Depois que você pegar o jeito, vai produzir relatórios brincando...hehe